# Swap image src using AJAX but don't reload repeatedly

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am creating a webpage containing a radio stream with accompanying album art. I am updating the album art by querying an XML file every 10 seconds and comparing the content of an xml tag against the src of an image currently being shown.

I have come up with the below script. The problem I am having is that if 'albumart' (the xml tag) is empty I am displaying 'generic.png' (see the last if/else) but this generic.png is being reloaded (fading in and out) every time the script repeats.

Is there a simple way I stop the image from reloading and fading in and out constantly?

```
function checkalbumart() {
jQuery.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "xml-file.php",
     dataType: "xml",
     success: function(xml) {
          jQuery(xml).find('currenttrack').each(function() {
               xmlalbumart = jQuery(this).find('albumart').text();
          });
          currentalbumart = jQuery('#albumart img').attr('src');

          if (xmlalbumart != currentalbumart ) {
               if (xmlalbumart) {
                    jQuery('#albumart').fadeTo( "fast" , 0, function () {
                         jQuery('#albumart img').attr('src', xmlalbumart);
                    }).fadeTo( "fast", 1);
               } else {
                    jQuery('#albumart').fadeTo( "fast" , 0, function () {
                         jQuery('#albumart img').attr('src', './img/generic.png');
                    }).fadeTo( "fast", 1);
               }
          }
     }
}).always(function() {
     setTimeout(updateshow, 10000);
});

}

checkalbumart();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if currentalbumart is set to the generic image, try the below code:

```
function checkalbumart() {
jQuery.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "xml-file.php",
     dataType: "xml",
     success: function(xml) {
          jQuery(xml).find('currenttrack').each(function() {
               xmlalbumart = jQuery(this).find('albumart').text();
          });
          currentalbumart = jQuery('#albumart img').attr('src');

          if (xmlalbumart != currentalbumart ) {
               if (xmlalbumart) {
                    jQuery('#albumart').fadeTo( "fast" , 0, function () {
                         jQuery('#albumart img').attr('src', xmlalbumart);
                    }).fadeTo( "fast", 1);
               } else if(currentalbumart != './img/generic.png') {
                    jQuery('#albumart').fadeTo( "fast" , 0, function () {
                         jQuery('#albumart img').attr('src', './img/generic.png');
                    }).fadeTo( "fast", 1);
               }
          }
     }
}).always(function() {
     setTimeout(updateshow, 10000);
});

}

checkalbumart();
```